# How to copy an image to a corrupt bootflash?

Tags: cisco-nexus

Hi i am trying to copy an image from my ftp server onto a nexus 3500 switch (N3K-C3048TP-1GE) but the switch will not let me access the bootflash at all, is there anything I can do to recover the bootflash or boot into the device?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Your device is broken. Contact Cisco TAC.

Comment: I was able to access the bootflash, using the init-system command and copy the kick start and system images across but I now cant boot any of the  images, the error message "Size of image (37749919) not equal to size derived from the image (0), aborting" anyone seen this problem before?

Comment: do you have to format the flash first?  something like Router# erase slot0:, or Router# format flash:?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if someone is looking at this problem years later...

In my case, this issue is related to firmware settings. For NX-OS releases 7.x, the first boot option should not be "FwBoot" but "EFI Shell". Swapping the priority will resolve the issue.

I don't know if this is the same situation for NX-OS 6 (likely not), but you can try.